# How to replace a part of a function with another function?

Tags: python, random, combinatorics

This is my code for python:

```
def RandomCard():
    x=number[ran.randint(0,12)]
    y=suit[ran.randint(0,3)]
    print("Your card is the:", x, "of", y)

    
def AceOfSpades():
    count = 1
    x=number[ran.randint(0,12)]
    y=suit[ran.randint(0,3)]
    while x != 'Ace' or y != 'Spades':
        x=number[ran.randint(0,12)]
        y=suit[ran.randint(0,3)]
        count += 1
    else: 
        print("Your card is the:", x, "of", y)
        print("It took", count, "tries to get the Ace of Spades!")
```

how do I replace the

```
    x=number[ran.randint(0,12)]
    y=suit[ran.randint(0,3)]
```

in the `AceOfSpades()` fn with `RandomCard()` instead?

When I simply put `RandomCard()` in place for the  `x=number[ran.randint(0,12)] y=suit[ran.randint(0,3)]` , it did not function as I wanted it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return a tuple containing `x` and `y` from `RandomCard`.

```py
def RandomCard():
    x = number[ran.randint(0,12)]
    y = suit[ran.randint(0,3)]
    print("Your card is the:", x, "of", y)
    return x, y
```

Then, unpack it in `AceOfSpades`:

```py
x, y = RandomCard()
```